# Is it possible for django template url direct to another project?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have two projects called `blog`, `user_auth`, both are all django projects. In `blog` project, I need to do a user authentication. Of course we can do it in current `blog` project like the following.

```
<span class="sign-in">
    <a href="{% url 'blog:sign-in' %}">sign-in</a>
</span>
<span class="sign-up">
    <a href="{% url 'blog:sign-up' %}">sign-up</a>
</span>
```

The question is if we have more projects which also need to do user authentication, we will have many repeated codes.

Here `user_auth` project is to manage all the projects' user authentication. My question is if we can use `{% url %}` in a `templates` in  `blog` project to direct to `user_auth` project?

Comment: i guess you gonna need to use full url with Domain/IP to redirect to other Project.

Comment: @HemalPatel I agree